# Set a class variable in IEnumerator coroutine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ienumerator

I need to do some initialization work in `Update()`.

This intialization work takes some time, and I can't proceed with the usual code in `Update()` until this initialization has finished.

Also, this initialization requires some `WaitForSeconds()` to work.

I have therefore tried the following:

```
private bool _bInitialized = false;
private bool _bStarted = false;

void Update()
{
    if (!_bInitialized)
    {
         if (!_bStarted)
         {
             _bStarted = true;
             StartCoroutine(pInitialize());
         }
         return;
    }

    (...) do stuff that can only be done after initialization has been completed
}
```

However, it seems that I can't change the variable `_bInitialized` within the `IEnumerator`.

`_bInitialized` never becomes `true`:

```
private IEnumerator pInitialize()
{
    WiimoteManager.Cleanup(_wii);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);

    _wii = WiimoteManager.Wiimotes[0];
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);

    _wii.SetupIRCamera(IRDataType.BASIC);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);

    _bInitialized = true; //this doesn't seem to work
    yield return 0;
}
```

Could anybody tell me how to do that correctly?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you sure that the enumerator is being fully enumerated? i.e. every item is returned? What happens if you put a breakpoint on `_bInitialized = true`? Does it get executed?

Comment: Also you could use `var enumerator = pInitialize(); while ( enumerator.MoveNext() ) { }` which would enumerate all the values.

Comment: @WaiHaLee For some reason, breakpoints in VS are never hit for me. Any Debug.Log inside the IEnumerator is ignored. Thanks for your MoveNext hint. I will try that first.

Comment: You should try to debug your Coroutine. If no Debug.Log in the Coroutine is working, are you even sure that your coroutine is running ?

Comment: I browsed to the documentation of StartCorouting and WaitForSeconds,  can you get a print command to work, or is this not part of the unity library.  I see a lot of print("") statements in the example code

Comment: If breakpoints are not hit, you can try to add a [`Debugger.Break()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debugger.break) to the start of `pInitialize()` - that should be hit.

Comment: What may happen here is that your code in the coroutine is silently throwing and catching an exception, maybe some of the code in ``WiimoteManager`` has something to do with it.

Comment: I am pretty sure this is  caused by one or more of your functions.

Comment: adding a try catch around the WIIxx calls could indeed be usefull...

Comment: Keep in mind your coroutine can not return unless your function executions are over.

Comment: Your last `yield` is unnecessary. You can safely remove it.

Comment: Just in general: would doing your Coroutine in `IEnumerator Start()` instead be an option? Would save you 1 bool flag at least and some lines of code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that [`StartCoroutine`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html) isn't enumerating all the values for whatever reason.

As the `Enumerator` lazily generates its values, and not all the values are being generated,

```
_bInitialized = true;
```

is never called.

You can confirm this by adding

```
var enumerator = pInitialize(); while ( enumerator.MoveNext() )
{
    // do nothing - just force the enumerator to enumerate all its values
}
```

---

As suggested in [one of the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53724850/setting-a-class-variable-in-ienumerator-coroutine/53725005?noredirect=1#comment94303530_53724850) by [Antoine Thiry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6020412/antoine-thiry),

> What may happen here is that your code in the coroutine is silently throwing and catching an exception, maybe some of the code in `WiimoteManager` has something to do with it.

Comment: I think you're getting an exception in your Wiimote code and that stops execution of the Corotuine. Do a log before the WiimoteManager.Cleanup(_wii); and after this statement and see if the logs appear or not.

Comment: @ZohaibZaidi Thank you, it doesn't appear. I will first investigate what's going on there.