# String variable doesn't save the given value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, variables

I have a method which is downloading an JSON Array from my server and saving the value I need to a separate string. As you see on the specific comments in my snippet, it doesn't save the value for some reason.

```
public string sItemName;

void Start()
{
        StartCoroutine(GetItems());
}


IEnumerator GetItems()
    {
        string uri = "My Server URL";

        using (UnityWebRequest webRequest = UnityWebRequest.Get(uri))
        {
            // Request and wait for the desired page.
            yield return webRequest.SendWebRequest();

            string[] pages = uri.Split('/');
            int page = pages.Length - 1;

            switch (webRequest.result)
            {
                case UnityWebRequest.Result.ConnectionError:
                case UnityWebRequest.Result.DataProcessingError:
                    Debug.LogError(pages[page] + ": Error: " + webRequest.error);
                    break;
                case UnityWebRequest.Result.ProtocolError:
                    Debug.LogError(pages[page] + ": HTTP Error: " + webRequest.error);
                    break;
                case UnityWebRequest.Result.Success:
                    if (webRequest.isDone)
                    {
                        itemArray = JsonHelper.GetArray<ItemInformation>(webRequest.downloadHandler.text);
                        sItemName = itemArray[0].name;
                        Debug.Log("GetItems -" + sItemName); //OUTPUT: GetItems - Poison (Works fine!)
                        FillInformation();
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }


private void FillInformation()
{
    Debug.Log("FillInformation -" + sItemName); //OUTPUT: FillInformation -     (Without any reason, at this point the value is gone)
}
```

I can't find useful help on google and I'm getting frustrated soon..

Comment: Does it change if you yield for a frame?  `Debug.Log(..); yield return null; FillInformation();`

Comment: I would hazard a guess that you're creating multiple instances of the class or you have some other code executing. Either way it's in code you haven't shown us.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you showed itself.

Comment: I agree with @Enigmativity. Short path to getting it working may be to use `string.Copy()` to get a second copy of (instead of a reference to) the string inside `itemArray`.

Comment: Consider using Unity Jobs instead of coroutines as the latter may block your game loop.

Comment: This would not happen with he code you show here .. I suspect the code provided here is not the actual one you are using. Anyway, why not rather simply pass in the value like `FillInformation(itemArray[0].name);` and `private void FillInformation(string itemName){Debug.Log("FillInformation -" + itemName);}` Then you can be sure that nothing will change a field in the meantime (- which again anyway could not happen in your case if this was the actual code)

Comment: I will try one of your peovided solutions and the Problem ist, thats exactly my original Code, I just removed my URL. I already tried with debugging and after the point, it gets out of the "GetItems" Method, the Variable is empty..

Comment: Add an else-if to that check for webRequest.isDone and see if that's why your variable fails to be set. The only thing I can think of is that your code is not following the path you expected.

Comment: @djdanlib - It seems that the variable is being set. The OP shows the output of the log call.

Comment: Then it would appear the output from the compiler in this case is not as obvious as it ought to be. Doing some more research, other people had similar problems such as https://stackoverflow.com/a/54476313/691749 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/53724850/691749